# Keep aspect ratio of images in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I've a set of 3 images:

[image: responsive images]

I want them to keep their aspect ratio depending on the browser width.

I've tried flex-box but there is always a difference in height between left image and right images.

The actual solution I found was to put the left image in a background with `background-size: cover;`.

Is there a way with flex-box to manage an automatic ratio like this?

```css
.container-img {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: gold;
}
.picture-large {
  flex: 1 0 calc(77.6% - 10px);
}
.picture-large img {
  width: 100%;
}
.block-img {
  text-align: right;
}
.block-img img {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.block-img img:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-img">
  <div class="picture-large">
    <img src="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/originals/8a/70/5e/8a705e6e7d9dc34eb26cb41ac20ac9ca.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block-img">
    <img class="picture" src="http://static1.decosoon.com/70282-large_atch/puppy-kitten-hug-painting.jpg">
    <img class="picture" src="http://us.123rf.com/450wm/azalia/azalia1308/azalia130800062/21936902-fluffy-cat-in-a-pan--striped-not-purebred-kitten-kitten-on-a-white-background-small-predator-small-c.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used SaSS to achieve what you are asking.

Markup:

```
<div class="container-img">
  <div class="picture-large">
    <img src="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/originals/8a/70/5e/8a705e6e7d9dc34eb26cb41ac20ac9ca.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block-img">
    <img class="picture" src="http://static1.decosoon.com/70282-large_atch/puppy-kitten-hug-painting.jpg">
    <img class="picture" src="http://us.123rf.com/450wm/azalia/azalia1308/azalia130800062/21936902-fluffy-cat-in-a-pan--striped-not-purebred-kitten-kitten-on-a-white-background-small-predator-small-c.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

The following code is held within a default.scss file which I then used Scout to compile into a default.css file that browsers can read.

```
@charset 'UTF-8';

// Source: http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/top-10-scss-mixins#responsiveratio
@mixin responsive-ratio($x,$y, $pseudo: false) {
$padding: unquote( ( $y / $x ) * 100 + '%' );
@if $pseudo {
    &:before {
        @include pseudo($pos: relative);
        width: 100%;
    }
  }
}

// Source: http://aricedev.azurewebsites.net/perfectly-centering-images-with-dynamic-sizes/
@mixin flexbox {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
}

@mixin perfect-center {
@include flexbox;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
}


.container-img {
width:100%;
display: flex;
flex-basis: 100%;
background: gold;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

  .picture-large {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  object-fit: contain;

  // Ratio based on defined 1150px by 700px dimensions
  // Caluclated at: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/
  @include responsive-ratio(23,14);
    img {max-width:100%; height:auto;}
  }
  .block-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:30%;
  float:right;
  background:green;
  // Ratio based on equal width and height dimensions defined
  @include responsive-ratio(1,1);
  img {width:100%; max-width:350px; max-height:350px;
    &.picture {}
  }
 }
}
```

default.css output as follows:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.container-img {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-basis: 100%;
background: gold;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.container-img .picture-large {
float: left;
width: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
}
.container-img .picture-large img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.container-img .block-img {
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 30%;
float: right;
background: green;
}
.container-img .block-img img {
width: 100%;
max-width: 350px;
max-height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: There's still space at top and bottom of the image

Comment: @romuleald If you mean around the entire frame, that is the margin being set by default to the body which can be removed by doing body:margin:0; as for the 'space' at the top and bottom of the little dog image, that is part of the actual image and nothing to do with the code. Use inspect element to see for yourself or duplicate the cat image and it will be fine.

Comment: I see that you're using `object-fit` that's not supported by IE. The yellow background show that there's still margin inside